# Is this function field extension a Galois extension ?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, normalization, fields, branched-covers

**Setting and question**

Let $X$ be a variety over an algebraically closed field of null characteristic, and let $C$ be a (regular if you want) curve included in $X$.
Consider $X'$ the normalization of $X$ and $C^*$ the sheaf-theoric pull-back of $C$ in $X$. Assume that $C^*$ is reduced, or even regular if you want.

The function field of each irreducible component of $C^*$ gives an extension of the function field of $C$. On all the examples that I've been able to compute, these extensions are Galois extension. How to prove it as a general fact ?

---

**Example**

Let $X$ be the surface defined by $A = k[x,y,z]/(x^2-zy^2)$, and let $C$ be the curve given by $(x,y)$.  Then $A'$ is $A[x/y]$, — that is to say $k[u,y,z]/(u^2-z)$, with $u=x/y$ —, and $C^*$ is given in $A'$ by the ideal $(y)$.

Thus, the field extension is $k(\sqrt{z}) | k(z)$, which is Galois.

Comment: Minor remark : you might want to assume $\mathrm{car}(k)=0$ in your question (in your example the field extension is not separable if $\mathrm{car}(k)=2$).

Comment: Yes I do ! Thank you for your remark.

Comment: No, this is typically not correct.  In affine space with coordinates $x$,$y$ and $z$, consider the variety cut out by the single equation $y^3-3yz^2-xz^3$.  This is not normal; the normalization is obtained by adjoining the fraction $u=y/z$.  The normalization is itself isomorphic to a hypersurface in the affine space with coordinates $x$, $u$, and $z$ with equation $u^3-3u-x$.  The curve in the original variety cut out by $y=z=0$ pulls back to the smooth curve cut out by $z=0$.  The map between the curves is degree $3$ and not Galois.

Comment: @Jason : Maybe you could write this as an answer, so the question doesn't remain in the "unanswered" category.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As requested by Francois: No, this is typically not correct. In affine space with coordinates $x$,$y$ and $z$, consider the variety cut out by the single equation $y^3−3yz^2−xz^3$. This is not normal; the normalization is obtained by adjoining the fraction $u=y/z$. The normalization is itself isomorphic to a hypersurface in the affine space with coordinates $x$, $u$, and $z$ with equation $u^3−3u−x$. The curve in the original variety cut out by $y=z=0$ pulls back to the smooth curve cut out by $z=0$. The map between the curves is degree 3 and not Galois.